# 2 Hibernate entities on the same database table. Is this possible?

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a modular Webproject with default functionality that can be extended using a "plugin" which is an additional java library.

The "core" project knows a User entity that is mapped to the User table.
The plugin project extends this User as an ExtendedUser which is also mapped to the same table-

Both entities should co-exists, where User only knows some of the columns.

Both entities are declared in different libraries included on the same classapth.

How do you get this to work with hibernate?

Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if you had any progress with this..

Comment: That [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667930/2-jpa-entities-on-the-same-table) seems to talk more or less of the same thing...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean that `ExtendedUser` is a class that extends `User`, then you can use Hibernate's "table-per-class-hierarchy" inheritance strategy.  See the [docs here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass).  Using annotations, you use `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` (see docs 2.2.4.2 [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168)).

Comment: However, User should still co-exists as its own entitiy and be referenced by other entities. As the table marked @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE), is not marked with @Entity, it will not be recognized as an identity of its own.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried once to map a table to two Java entities (without an inheritance scheme). I just wanted to experiment some different mappings while preserving the old entity.

The thing is if your User and ExtenderUser both share the same collection of entities X, Hibernate will complain about not knowing which entity X is connected back to: User or ExtenderUser.

So bottom line, in mine case it didn't work, and it's right not to.

I haven't tried an inheritance scheme, but from what you're saying, you don't one either.