# Criteria builder joinSet fetches Object instead of Set of Objects

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria, criteria-api

I have 2 entites with relation OneToMany.

```
@Entity
public class Table1 implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;

private String field1;
private String field2;
private String field3;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "table1_id")
private Set<Table2> tables2;
}

@Entity
public class Table2 {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String field1;
}
```

I want to fetch data from Table1 to additional object Table1Trimmed using criteria builder

```
public class Table1Trimmed {

    private Long id;
    private Set<Table2> tables2;

    public Table1Trimmed(Long id, Set<Table2> tables2) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tables2 = tables2;
    }

}
```

I am doing it like this

```
CriteriaQuery<Table1Trimmed> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Table1Trimmed.class);
Root<Table1> table1Root = cq.from(Table1.class);
SetJoin<Table1, Table2> tables2Join = table1Root.joinSet("tables2");
cq.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(Table1Trimmed.class, table1Root.get("id"), tables2Join));
List<Table1Trimmed> tables1Trimmed = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

But when i am running my app i receive this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Table1Trimmed.<init>(java.lang.Long, Table2)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getConstructorFor(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.CriteriaQueryImpl.populateAndSetConstructorSelection(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.CriteriaQueryImpl.select(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:93)
```

It means that framework want to inject object of class Table2 into my Table1Trimmed constructor instead of Set of Table2 objects. Is there any way to achieve this using criteria builder?

Comment: you cannot select a multi-valued field in a JPQL or Criteria query (and that is effectively what you're doing by using the construct). See the JPA spec JPQL "BNF" notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best resolution is to create additional read only entity which contains only specific fields.

```
@ReadOnly
@Entity("table1trimmed")
@Table("table1")
public class Table1Trimmed {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table1_id")
    private Set<Table2> tables2;

}
```

Ok i have found an indirect answer here [1]

[1]
[2 JPA entities on the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667930/2-jpa-entities-on-the-same-table)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two problems with what you're trying to do. First is that you are getting multiple rows with your query. You get a row for each entry in the `tables2` set:

```
-----------------------------------------
|  TABLE1.ID  |  TABLE2.ID |  TABLE1_ID |
-------------+-------------+-------------
|     1      |     1       |     1      |
|     1      |     2       |     1      |
-----------------------------------------
```

Which is OK if your fetching into `Table1`, but not OK if your constructing within JPQL or a CriteriaQuery. A `Construct` statement can only do one row, one class. If you make a `Table1Trimmed` that has a `Table2` constructor you'll see that you get a result for every `Table2` entry instead of a result for every `Table1` entry.

Second, there is no constructor for `Set` that a JPA provider can use. A `Set`, or `HashSet` can be constructed from another `Collection`, but, again, there is nothing in the `Construct` construct that can construct a `Collection` of `Table2s`. (Just had to say that! :).

Comment: Understood, but do you know how to achieve, what i am trying to do, using Criteria Builder?

Comment: And i mean in pretty way because i want to omit some manual object grouping etc.

Comment: Yes, creating a smaller, ReadOnly Entity makes sense